# How to make a distorted scanned color effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, effects, distort

I already know how to make a shape distortion.

But, I can't really figure out how to make 'color' distortion like the 'spectrum' in the example below.

[image]

Comment: Distort color channel not layer.

Comment: Hi mahdo, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

To start & keep it simple > flatten your image and go to RGB mode. Open the channels palette and select the Red channel only. It should be the only selected channel (should be light-blue). Create a selection and move the selection & artwork around a bit. Now go back to the RGB channel (all should be light-blue). Now do the same for the other channels. Something like this happens.

[image]

Keep in mind you can also paste black and white images into these channels (since the black you see is a representation of the red or the green or the blue). Where these tints mix the spectrum appears.

So you could create 3 different layers of your image in black & white and paste each layer into the R, G & B channels until you are happy with the result. You just need to visualise it in your head and create the b&w layers on top of each other so you get some idea.